# What does 'args' means on CliBuilder?

Tags: scripting, groovy

I'm a newbie on Groovy and I'm trying to understand what's the meaning of args attribute on CliBuilder. I'm not sure if it means the max number of parameters that an option can take.

I have something like

```
import java.text.*

def test(args) {
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'test.groovy brand instance')
    cli.with {
        h longOpt: 'help', 'Show usage information'
    }

    cli.b(argName:'brand', args: 1, required: true, 'brand name')
    cli.p(argName:'ports', args: 2, required: true, 'ports')

    def options = cli.parse(args)
    if (!options) {
           return
    }

    if (options.h) {
            cli.usage()
            return
    }

    println options.b
    println options.p

}

test(args)
```

When I call the script I use `groovy test.groovy -b toto -p 10 11`

But I get:

```
toto
10
```

Shouldn't I get 10 11 for the -p option? If not, what does args mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This post here](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2009/10/04/groovy-clibuilder-with-multiple-arguments/#hide) should explain how the `args` parameter works

Basically, you need to add a plural `s` to your `println` line like so:

```
println options.bs
```

That should then print:

```
[10, 11]
```